# Python скачивание видео с сайта

Tags: python, download

Подскажите каким способом можно быстрее всего скачать видео?

```
ufr = requests.get(results.get('data-href'), stream=True)
```

Таким способом скорость меньше "нормальной" раз в 10, иногда падает еще меньше.

Answer (score 0):

Переменная `ufr` принимает ссылку на видео?
Попробуй библиотеку wget.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]